# Fluent NHibernate: Model Markov chain

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, statistics

I want to use Fluent NHibernate to model a [Markov chain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). It's basically a set of different states with transition probabilities between the states.

I want to map the transition probabilities into MarkovState.TransitionProbabilities as a Dictionary. I want to use the NEXT state as key (using either MarkovState or int as key), so that I can do lookups like:

```
float probability = currentState.TransitionProbabilities[nextState.Id].Probability;
```

My database model:

```
CREATE TABLE MarkovState
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    StateContent varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TransitionProbability
(        
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CurrentState_Id int NOT NULL,
    NextState_Id int NOT NULL,
    Probability float NOT NULL
 );
```

My classes:

```
public class MarkovState
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual string StateContent { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<int, TransitionProbability> TransitionProbabilities { get; set; }
}

public class TransitionProbability
{
    public virtual int Id { get; private set; }
    public virtual MarkovState CurrentState { get; set; }
    public virtual MarkovState NextState { get; set; }
    public virtual float Probability { get; set; }
}
```

And my maps:

```
class MarkovStateMap : ClassMap<MarkovState>
{
    public MarkovStateMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.StateContent);
        HasMany<TransitionProbability>(x => x.TransitionProbabilities)
            .AsMap(x => x.NextState.Id)
            .KeyColumn("CurrentState_Id")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse();            
    }
}

class TransitionProbabilityMap : ClassMap<TransitionProbability>
{
    public TransitionProbabilityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Probability);
        References(x => x.CurrentState);
        References(x => x.NextState);
    }
}
```

However, this mapping seems to use `CurrentState` as the key, and not the `NextState`. I don't even know if this model is possible. Please suggest alternatives if you think this model isn't valid.

Comment: I can't help but think you should be storing this as a simple matrix and using tools designed for these types of mathematical problems (e.g. Math.NET).

Comment: @Tristan: Seconded, unless there is some good reason for using a database. @Francois Botha: Why do you want to use a database? Where is your data coming from?

Comment: The transition probabilities will be managed by an admin user (an actuary) and hence we're storing it in a database. The number of states could also possible change, although that will not happen often.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but your HasMany mapping points to CurrentState_Id. I think you're mappings should look like:

```
class MarkovStateMap : ClassMap<MarkovState>
{
    public MarkovStateMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.StateContent);
        HasMany<TransitionProbability>(x => x.TransitionProbabilities)
            .AsMap(x => x.NextState.Id)
            .KeyColumn("NextState_Id")
            .Not.LazyLoad()
            .Inverse();            
    }
}

class TransitionProbabilityMap : ClassMap<TransitionProbability>
{
    public TransitionProbabilityMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Probability);
        References(x => x.CurrentState, "Id");
        References(x => x.NextState, "Id");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in the end I abandoned the Map and went with a normal IList.